# How prevent JQgrid's Search Filter from opening behind the jqueryUI dialog?

Tags: jquery-ui, search, jqgrid, dialog

The code below uses JQgrid within a JqueryUI dialog.  When the 'Find Records' button is pressed first time, filter form appears fine in front of the grid.  Close the filter, fine.  Open the filter, fine, close it fine.

But the 3rd time press Find Records' button, the filter form appears behind the dialog form.   Any ideas as to cause/solution -- so that the filter form always appears in front of the grid and the dialog?   Thanks...

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8">  
<title>tabs demo</title>  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My First Grid</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

</head>

<body> 
<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" title="My Test">
    <table id="MyGrid"></table>
    <div id="MyGridDiv" MyGrid>
    </div>
</div>       

<script>
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false});
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {  
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );});
</script>

<script>
jQuery("#MyGrid").jqGrid({
datatype: "local",
height: 250,
colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
colModel:[
{name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
{name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"},
{name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
{name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
{name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},     
{name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},      
{name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
],
multiselect: true,
pager: '#MyGridDiv',  <!-- required for search dialog -->
caption: "Test"
});
var mydata = [
{id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-                01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
{id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
{id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
{id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
{id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
{id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
{id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
{id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
{id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
];
for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)
jQuery("#MyGrid").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);

<!-- Search options-->              
jQuery("#MyGrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#MyGridDiv',
{
del:false,add:false,edit:false},{},{},{},{multipleSearch:true}
);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also a similar situation and fixed by adding modal:true in jquery dialog properties.

change your code from

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false});
```

to

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false,modal:true});
```

Please keep in mind, if modal set to true, the dialog will have modal behavior; other items on the page will be disabled, i.e., cannot be interacted with. Modal dialogs create an overlay below the dialog but above other page elements.

Answer (score 0):

But what if the dialog needs to not be modal?  Is there some way to alter the z-index of the Search Form?

Comment: You should post this as a comment or another question.

Answer (score 0):

There are situations that you want to keep everything with modals option set to be true.

My solution is to create an extra jquery UI dialog functions the search and have the default search offered by jqGrid removed. This should work perfectly with any jqueryui dialog behind since the pop up uses JqueryUI itself, disregarding the 'modal' option is true or false.

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid().navgrid("#myGridPager", {
   search:false
}).navButtonAdd("#myGridPager", {
   caption:""
   , buttonicon:"ui-icon-search"
   , onClickButton: function(){
      $("#myGridSearchDialog").dialog("open");
   }
});
```

Hope this helps.